# Select all matching elements in PHPUnit Selenium 2 test case

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

It is simple to select an element by specifying its class, in PHPUnit Selenium 2 test case:

```
$element = $this->byClassName("my_class");
```

However, even if there are two items of `my_class`, the selector picks only one of them (probably the first one). How can I select all of them? I'd appreciate something like `allByClassName`:

```
$elements = $this->allByClassName("my_class");
foreach($elements as $element) {
    doSomethingWith($element);
}
```

Is there anything like `allByClassName` in PHPUnit Selenium 2 extension?

Comment: Hmm, your code looks a bit different than mine but I am also using the NearSoft library. Is your `$this` a wrapper for the web driver? My code for finding multiple elements looks something like this: `$this->_driver->findElements(By::className("my_class"));`. Maybe somehow that can help you go in the right direction, I don't know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pavel, you can find guidance on how to select multiple elements here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/b8c6494b977f79098e748343455f129af3fdb292/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php

lines 92-98:

```
public function testMultipleElementsSelection()
{
    $this->url('html/test_element_selection.html');
    $elements = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('div'));
    $this->assertEquals(4, count($elements));
    $this->assertEquals('Other div', $elements[0]->text());
}
```

(This file contains the tests for the Selenium2TestCase class itself, so it's great for learning about its capabilities)

Following this method, you could retrieve all elements with a certain class like this:

```
    $elements = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('*[class="my_class"]'));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: (-1) $elements = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('*[class="my_class"]')) will only return elements with a single class of 'my_class'. It will not return elements with multiple classes.

Comment: Took me a while to realize that I have to write "css selector" as is - and not replace it by a actual css selector

Comment: It's not optimal, but actually browsing the source does show you what's happening http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/source-class-PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element_Accessor.html#70

Answer (score 1):

To select multiple elements by class, use:

```
$elements = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('.my_class'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The WebDriver method [findElements(By by)](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, so I tried the solution that @David posted. It works, but somehow Selenium was trying to find the element again and again, so my test time increased 15 secs just on this.

To be faster, I ended up creating a ID for my class and counting the elements inside:

```
$elements = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('#side-menu li'));
$this->assertEquals(0, count($elements));
```